# How to do this without tables

Tags: html, html-table, css-float

I know that it's been an ongoing discussion, and that float:right is supposed to be the answer to avoiding the use of tables for formatting, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the following without tables.  The labels will change based on language, so fixed widths can't be used.

[image: Form using Table]

I can't seem to get float:right to work when the inputs are different widths.  Here's the HTML I used with a table...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head />
<body>
    <style>
        .left {
            width:1%;
            white-space:nowrap;
            text-align:right;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <form>
        <table
            width="400">
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        style="display:table-cell; width:100%"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Telephone Number:</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="text" style="width: 30px;"
                    />-<input
                        type="text" style="width: 30px;"
                    />-<input
                        type="text" style="width: 40px;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                    />Okay to leave the package without a signature.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="left">Delivery Notes:</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea
                        rows="5"
                        style="display:table-cell;
                        width:100%"
                    ></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the text is to be translated to other languages, wouldn't it be better to have label text on one line and input types on next lines?

Comment: Except that isn't the desired layout :)